# Oracle, C# WebService and PowerBI

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, web-services, powerbi

I have some PowerBI dashboards that cannot directly access the Oracle database due to company security rules. Firstly, I would like to know if it's possible to create a middle layer in C# by creating a WebService that the PowerBI dashboards can consume data from. My question is, is it possible to create this service using C#, and secondly, is it the best technology to create this middle layer or bridge between the database and the Oracle dashboards. I appreciate any suggestions that use .NET as a bridge.
Dear friends, I have some PowerBI dashboards that cannot directly access the Oracle database due to company security rules. Firstly, I would like to know if it's possible to create a middle layer in C# by creating a WebService that the PowerBI dashboards can consume data from. My question is, is it possible to create this service using C#, and secondly, is it the best technology to create this middle layer or bridge between the database and the Oracle dashboards. I appreciate any suggestions that use .NET as a bridge.

Comment: wouldn't that be a use case for the on prem data gateway? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/gateway/service-gateway-install

Comment: Unfortunately, I have limited network access, which prevents me from creating new gateways or accessing on-premise cloud services. Therefore, I still need to rely on good old-fashioned code.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Just write a .NET program using the [ODP.NET NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core).  Of course that program has to connect directly to your Oracle database.

You can either write a console app to extract the Oracle data to another location, or a web service that Power BI could hit directly.